# how to fix Error Code: 1054. Unknown column in my sql

Tags: mysql

i write below code and i have Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'referenceinfo.mid' in 'on clause'
    `create table newenron as 
    SELECT employeelist.eid
    ,employeelist.firstName
    ,employeelist.lastName
    ,employeelist.Email_id
    ,employeelist.status
    ,message.mid
    ,message.sender
    ,message.subject
    ,message.body
    ,message.folder
    ,recipientinfo.rid
    ,recipientinfo.mid
    ,recipientinfo.rvalue
    ,referenceinfo.rfid
    ,referenceinfo.mid
    ,referenceinfo.reference
    FROM employeelist
    INNER JOIN message ON employeelist.Email_id = message.sender
    INNER JOIN recipientinfo ON message.mid = referenceinfo.mid
    INNER JOIN referenceinfo ON recipientinfo.rid = referenceinfo.rfid`                 how can i fix it?
thank for your taking time.

Comment: here is the dataset info: http://www.ahschulz.de/enron-email-data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
 INNER JOIN recipientinfo ON message.mid = referenceinfo.mid
```

you are joining the table **recipientinfo** but make reference to **referenceinfo**?

From what I could tell,

- recipientinfo
- referenceinfo

Are two different tables.

What you probably want is

```
INNER JOIN recipientinfo ON message.mid = recipientinfo.mid
```

or

```
INNER JOIN referenceinfo ON message.mid = referenceinfo.mid
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled a column name. But from this I can't see which one.

Comment: i have this error code 1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'